# how is it possible to set alpha over as default for strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to set "alpha over" as default in strip? It's pretty annoying to have to change this setting for every strip...

and if yes, how? ;)

Comment: Yes, it is annoying. No, there is not a natural way to set "alpha over" as default from what I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the add/import settings, but you can batch change settings by selecting all strips needed, right click and select Copy to Selection.
[image]

Many properties will add values to full selection with +alt pressed, but it doesn't seem to be implemented for the blend modes.

Comment: yeah, thanks, this will make it a bit easier so